# How to query Cassandra from a certain node and get the data from only that node own?

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

Cassandra use consistent hash to manage data, and after we use Cassandra driver to connect the cluster, the node we connect to may query from other nodes in the cluster to get the result. But for my current situation, I'm doing some testing for my algorithm, I want to give a certain tokenRange and query the data in the tokenRange and on a certain node, if some data in the tokenRange isn't in this node, I don't want the node query other node to get the result. Is it possible and how to achieve it?
I find [Cassandra Python driver: force using a single node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792027/cassandra-python-driver-force-using-a-single-node/34795837#) but this solution only provide the client's connection pool connect to a certain node, the node will still query other nodes.

Comment: Have you also tried to set the consistency level to one?

Comment: Yes, I set the consistency level to one. And I find a document explain what the node means, the node we set policy to access is contract point. https://teddyma.gitbooks.io/learncassandra/content/client/which_node_to_connect.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/policies.html#cassandra.policies.WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy) and CL.ONE like linked in other question.

You can also extend the Statement to include a host and a custom load balancing policy to send the request to the host in the wrapper. Extend a policy and override `make_query_plan`, something like (untested just scratch, consider following pseudo code)

```
class StatementSingleHostRouting(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy):
  def make_query_plan(self, working_keyspace=None, query=None):
    if query.host:
      return [query.host]
    return DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.make_query_plan(self, working_keyspace, query)
```

If that host doesn't own the data it will still query other replicas though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I want the host don't query other replicas, is there any lower level apis we can use to achieve that? I think for example, the devops may also need this function to find if there is something wrong in the system.

Comment: You would need to right a custom replication factor in cassandra. If you send a query to any host the host will act as coordinator sending read to appropriate replicas. There is no way to tell cassandra not to do that. Devops can use `nodetool getendpoints` to find replicas and can cqlsh on one of those hosts and use TRACE ON; it will tell them exactly which hosts and sstables were involved in query. If using CL.ONE on a replica it will just be be that host. If using above code you can accomplish that by getting the replicas as well when defining statement.

Comment: I am a Cassandra devops person by the way and thats how I regularly do it (getendpoints/trace).